# Find all local maxima in a one-dimensional array

Tags: java, array

I implemented the following class (it works) and I just want to hear your opinions about best practices and what can be improved. The idea was to do it using mostly arrays.

The class just finds the peak elements in an array with respect to their neighbors. The first element and the last element are ignored.

**Example**: `{3, 15, 5, 20, 10}`
**Answer**:  `{15, 20}`

```
package findpeak;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class ArrayPeak
{
    private final int[] ARRAY;
    private final int LEN;
    private static final int IGNORE_FIRST_POSITION = 0;
    private final int IGNORE_LAST_POSITION;

    public ArrayPeak(int[] array)
    {
        this.ARRAY = array;
        this.LEN = this.ARRAY.length;
        this.IGNORE_LAST_POSITION = this.LEN - 1;
    }

    public List<Integer> findPeaks()
    {
        List<Integer> peaks = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int position = 0; position < LEN; position++)
        {
            int output = 0;
            if (position != IGNORE_FIRST_POSITION && position != IGNORE_LAST_POSITION)
            {
                int[] trippleArray =
                {
                    ARRAY[position - 1], ARRAY[position], ARRAY[position + 1]
                };
                output = checkPeak(trippleArray);
            }
            peaks.add(output);
        }

        return filterZeros(peaks);
    }

    private static int checkPeak(int[] inputArray)
    {
        int peak = 0;
        if (inputArray[1] > inputArray[0] && inputArray[1] > inputArray[2])
        {
            peak = inputArray[1];
        }
        return peak;
    }

    private static List<Integer> filterZeros(List<Integer> list)
    {
        List<Integer> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (list.get(i) != 0)
            {
                filteredList.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        return filteredList;
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, what's the expected output with test cases such as `{1}` or `{1,2}` where the first/last/only element is a local maximum?  What about empty arrays?  (I can infer that from the code, but it helps people if you're explicit about the edge cases.)

Comment: Another case that might fail: `{0,1,1,0}`

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't involve an instance of a class: you can (and should) implement this as a standalone static method, which takes the input array as a parameter and returns the peaks. Introducing a class to record the state is just introducing complexity which will make the code harder to maintain without providing any benefit.

I would also like some documentation explaining exactly what the method does: for example, it doesn't return non-positive peaks, and (as Toby Speight's comment indicates) some might thing it would return plateaus. Basically you need a better specification, and that needs to appear as documentation, so that the intention of the code is completely unambiguous (for the benefit of the implementer, maintainer, and consumer). I would not expect a method like this to return the heights of peaks, rather than their position.

---

`IGNORE_FIRST_POSITION` sounds like the name of a `boolean`, not an int. You'd be better off, I think, changing the `for` loop to start at 1, end at `array.Length - 1`, and include a comment explaining why this is the case.

---

I like that `CheckPeak` is its own method because it puts the corresponding logic 'all in one place', but I don't like that you are creating a new array every time you check for a peak: I would much prefer you pass the array and candidate position as parameters, and it checks 'in-place'. This is a simpler API (the current one lacks any specification that it takes an array of three parameters), and will reduce the overhead from calling the method.

I also don't like that it returns the height of the peak, rather than whether or not a peak appears: this too is lacking documentation (though granted it is private, so it isn't as important as the public method). Much better to return `true` or `false` if it is a peak, then add the peak to the list of peaks if it returns `true`, otherwise do not (then you can remote the confusing `filterZeros` at the end).

This can also remove the unpleased `output` variable, which is defined too early. It only has meaning once it is assigned, and if it isn't assigned it just has a default value you will filter anyway, so you might as well declare and assign it in one.

---

Really tiny thing that is almost completely subjective: I'd prefer to write

```
if (inputArray[1] > inputArray[0] && inputArray[1] > inputArray[2])
```

as

```
if (inputArray[0] < inputArray[1] && inputArray[1] > inputArray[2])
```

It keeps them 'in order, and makes it a little easier to feel what is going on.

---

Your code only works with `Integers`: if I wanted to find peaks in a `Double[]`, I would need to write a new class. You might want to make it generic on a type `T` that implements `Comparable<T>`. This can create some confusion with floating point types (i.e. `NaN`s), but by depending on a basic interface, your code will be reusable and harder to 'get wrong'.

You might also consider taking an abstract collection as a parameter; it's good that you return `List<T>` rathern than `ArrayList<T>`.

---

Example rewrite (disclaimer: untested, and I don't know Java, and I'm running out of time...):

```
public class ArrayPeak
{
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> findPeaks(T[] array)
    {
        List<T> peaks = new ArrayList<>();

        // ignore first and last elements
        for (int position = 1; position < array.length - 1; position++)
        {
            if (checkPeak(array, position)
            {
                peaks.add(array[position]);
            }
        }

        return peaks;
    }

    private static <T extends Comparable<T>> int checkPeak(T[] array, int position)
    {
        if (inputArray[position - 1].compareTo(inputArray[position]) < 0 && inputArray[position].compareTo(inputArray[position + 1]) > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: minor addendum: the `checkPeak` method can be simplified to directly return the if-condition: `return inputArray[...];`

Answer (score 1):

**KISS**

**K**eep **I**t **S**hort **S**imple. Your code seems to be overly complicated compared to what you want to achieve. The invocation of a class isn't really necessary, for your use case a simple static utility method would be enough.

**Memory usage and runtime**

You are allocating an array just to compare three numbers:

```
int[] trippleArray =
{
    ARRAY[position - 1], ARRAY[position], ARRAY[position + 1]
};
```

This could easily be done inplace:

```
if (ARRAY[position - 1] < ARRAY[position] && ARRAY[position] > ARRAY[position + 1])
{
    peaks.add(ARRAY[position]);
}
```

In consequence `filterZeros()` is not necessary anymore and you get rid of a linear runtime method. By the way returning non-existing results with a special value, in your case returning `0` when there is no peak and removing these special values afterwards is a huge runtime issue, as you get linear runtime just for iterating over the entire input again. Instead you could return a `boolean` if a result exists or make use of `null`.

**Variable naming**

`CONSTANT_CASE` is reserved to constants, i.e. static final fields. This is not the case for `ARRAY`, `LEN` and `IGNORE_LAST_POSITION`. By the way a constant for the first index in an array isn't really necessary as everyone knows the first index is `0` and the second is `1`. Furthermore `IGNORE_FIRST_POSITION` and `IGNORE_LAST_POSITION` sound like `boolean` variables, consider a better name.

**Improved version**

```
public static List<Integer> findPeaks(int[] input) {
    List<Integer> peaks = new LinkedList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
        if (input[i - 1] < input[i] && input[i] > input[i + 1]) {
            peaks.add(input[i]);
        }
    }
    return peaks;
}
```

Comment: Last time I checked, KISS meant "Keep It Simple, Stupid", but your version does sound much better.

Comment: Yeah, that's the most common abbreviation, but as far as I know both versions exist.

Comment: I'd be disinclined to use a `LinkedList` here, because it increases the complexity of lookups for the consumer (likely use-case) - and in doing so probably goes against general expectations - without changing the complexity of the method itself.

Comment: Correct, on the other hand an `ArrayList` isn't the best solution either, as its add operation might end in linear complexity. In my opinion a `Set` would be the best solution, but the question stated a `List` return type.